# Datadog ddtrace with async Google PubSub publishing

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, trace, datadog, apm

Is there a way to ddtrace (APM) the async pubsub publishing in Python?
I am publishing events asynchronously and have no visibility of when they occur or how much time the publishing itself takes.

I can only measure the time from the publish itself until the callback is called (message has been published).

1. Publishing event in async mode (getting a future)
2. some library pubsub code which actually publishes it whenever it gets CPU time
3. Callback is triggered after publishing is done

so I can measure 1 to 3 which doesn't show me exactly when 2 started.

any ideas?